# How to I write a Specs2 matcher for "a,b,c".containsAllOf("b","a")?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, specs2

I'm new to the Scala/Play 2.1/Specs2 stack, so please excuse me if this question seems simpleton, but I am having difficulty writing a spec to test the case of "String contains the word 'GET'".  I've got a Play 2.1 Action that returns an Access-Control-Allow-Methods header value like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

My Spec has no problem doing straight equality checks on other headers, but I have been unable to figure out how to check the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header for each of GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, and OPTIONS.  I've expected something like "must contains("GET") to work but the IDE goes red on this with some:

```
type mismatch;  found   : org.specs2.matcher.ContainMatcher[String]  required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[Option[String]]   SessionsSpec.scala  /dm2-server/test/admin  line 53 Scala Problem
```

My spec looks like...

```
"send 200 on OPTIONS request on valid route" in {
  running(FakeApplication()) {
    var fakeReq = FakeRequest("OPTIONS", "/admin/sessions")
    val Some(result) = route(fakeReq)
    status(result) must equalTo(OK)
    header(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, result) must equalTo(Some("*"))
    header(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, result) must equalTo(Some(CONTENT_TYPE))
    val expectedMethods = Seq(GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, "OPTIONS")
    header(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, result) must containAllOf(expectedMethods)
  }
}
```

How do I express the use case of "does this string contain all of these values" in Specs2?

Comment: What versions of scala and specs2 are you using?

Comment: Scala is 2.10.1.  If the Scala-IDE is to be believed, Specs2 version is specs2_21.10.jar.

Comment: One tip: instead of writing `equalTo(Some("*"))` you can write `beSome("*")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something similar to what you are trying to accomplish:

```
"A split option string " should{
  "be able to be verified with a containsAllOf matcher" in {
    val headerVal = Some("a, b, c, d, e")
    val expected = Seq("a", "e")

    headerVal must beSome
    headerVal.get.split(", ").toSeq must containAllOf(expected)
  }
}
```

The issue was that you were trying to take an `Option[String]` and use that in a `Traversable` matcher against a `Seq`.  To make that kind of comparison work, both items need to be `Traversable`.  To get to that point, I first make a check on the `Option` to make sure it's a `Some`. I then get it and split it on the comma and turn that into a `Seq`.  Once both pieces are `Traversable`, you can use that `containAllOf` matcher.

Comment: You can also do that in the same expression with: `headerVal must beSome.like { case value => value.split(",").toSeq must containAllOf(expected) }`